# HTML5 audio control stop button (as opposed to pause)

Tags: html, controller, html5-audio

I've been absolutely everywhere (I think) and can't seem to find a way to call a stop event in an html5 audio controller. My audio controller has a playlist where each track will play when selected or cycle through each track to the next. There's also a next button which works.

My play/pause button looks like this:

```
function playPause() {
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
    if(audioPlayer!=undefined) {
        if (audioPlayer.paused) {
            audioPlayer.play();
        } else {
            audioPlayer.pause();
        }
    } else {
        loadPlayer();
    }
}
```

I need a "Stop" button that stops the audio and goes back to the beginning of the track currently being played. I thought about using the current playback postion somehow, but can't get my head around that.

I've also tried this (adapted by advice here in another question), to no avail:

```
function stop() {
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
    }, false);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your play/pause is working, this should work for stop:

```
function stop() {
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
    audioPlayer.pause();
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
}
```

Comment: And so it does, perfectly! I had to add `[0]` after the tagname to get it to work with my playlists. Thank you!

(Sorry I can't vote it up with my pathetic reputation of 1.)

Comment: @yolise Yes, sorry, `getElementsByTagName` returns a list.  I'll vote your question up, that'll help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small demo code, where you can play, pause and stop an audio.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/RGJCf/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="play" id="playBtn" />
<input type="button" value="pause" id="pauseBtn" />
<input type="button" value="stop" id="stopBtn" />
```

**Jquery**

```
var source = "http://www.giorgiosardo.com/HTML5/audio/audio/sample.mp3"
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = source;

$("#playBtn").click(function () {
    audio.play();
});

$("#pauseBtn").click(function () {
    audio.pause();
});

$("#stopBtn").click(function () {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
});
```

[Source](http://yassershaikh.com/play-pause-and-stop-an-audio-in-html-5-by-example/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the music and abort the downloading operation you can use this code:

```
<button id="btnStop" onclick="player.src = ''; player.src = 'song.mp3';">Stop</button>
```

We are using java here to change the song src and then put it back there! Tricky but worky