# Object #<HTMLAudioElement> has no method 'stop'

Tags: javascript

```
$(function(){
    var clickhover     = $('.click');
        var clickaudio = clickhover.find('audio')[0];

    clickhover.hover(function(){
       clickaudio.play();
    }, function(){
       clickaudio.stop();
    });
}
```

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'stop' ? how do???

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653823/html5-audio-control-stop-button-as-opposed-to-pause ?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation, there are no `.stop()` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Methods

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For HTML5 audio element this method is called `.pause()`, not `.stop()`.

You can see this method usage (among others) on [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Controlling_media_playback).

Comment: Uggg. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

It's possible that you could create a `stop()` method (as one currently does not exist, hence the problem you face):

```
HTMLMediaElement.prototype.stop = function(){
    this.pause();
    this.currentTime = 0;
};
```

Using `HTMLMediaElement`, rather than `HTMLAudioElement`, should allow the same method to be called on both `audio` and `video` elements.

Comment: Upvote - I was going to include custom `stop()` in my answer as well, but I was too lazy ;)

Comment: Thank you kindly! :) I did consider updating the `pause()` method to return the `this`/node so that `currentTime` could be chained, but then I realised that was silly...

Comment: It worked for me even without the calling of pause function.